# Best way to store a SET bigger than 64

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a database of movies for my website and I'm redesigning it to make it more efficient.

The `movies` table has a field called `countries`. In this moment, the values are stored in `varchar`, using csv. For example:

```
Spain,France,Germany
```

This is very inneficient. For example, It's hard to select all movies from `France`.

I can't use a `set` because there are more than 64 different countries.
I could make a table of countries and another table that links `id_country` with `id_movie`. But then I need to make another `join` to get the movie data (like I do with actors o directors).

Any suggestions? Which could be the best way to store the countries information?

Comment: What's wrong with using a join? That's what relational databases are meant for.

Comment: It adds more complexity to my database. I just want to know it there's a different solution to this.

Comment: From my point of view a SET (which is a non-normalized solution) makes things more complicated. Using a JOIN is not something that qualifies as "complexity", it's what databases do.

Comment: Yes, it seems that separate tables is the best way to do this. Also, I need to store the values in a certain order, with a SET I can't do that. If you write your comment as an answer I will approve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my point of view a SET (which is a non-normalized solution) makes things more complicated.

Using a JOIN is not something that qualifies as "complexity", it's what databases are made for and are good at.

If you need to maintain a defined order of the elements you will have to add an extra "sort" column to that lookup table.

Comment: a JOIN requires the index of both tables to be present in RAM. On huge tables that might be a serious issue as a billion "integers" are quite a chunk of RAM data.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to store countries is in a table of countries. Include the ISO 3166 country code. Store the ISO code as a foreign key reference, and you won't need a join most of the time.

```
create table countries (
  iso_country_code char(3) primary key,
  country_name varchar(50) not null unique
);

insert into countries (country_name, iso_country_code) values
('AALAND ISLANDS', 'ALA'),
('AFGHANISTAN', 'AFG'),
('ALBANIA', 'ALB'),
...
('YEMEN', 'YEM'),
('ZAMBIA', 'ZMB'),
('ZIMBABWE', 'ZWE');

create table some_other_table_that_references_countries (
  some_key ... primary key,
  iso_country_code char(3) not null references countries (iso_country_code),
  ...
);
```

Most of the time, you probably won't need to do a join, because people can remember the country codes.